# How to customize Jmeter startup with Jmeter gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, gradle-plugin

I have created several Jmeter plugins that I need to use when executing my Jmeter scenario. 
When executing manually my scenario I execute the following command:

```
jmeter.sh -Jsearch_paths="/home/installMyPlugin/lib/ext" -Jplugin_dependency_paths="/home/installMyPlugin/lib"  -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -Dhostname=vm2ombre -n -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Djmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -l home/report/jmeter/result.jtl -t home/installMyPlugin/scenarii/test.jmx
```

It works, my plugins are loaded and the scenario is executed.

Now, I would like to execute the same command using the Jmeter plugin for Gradle.

I tried to configure the build.gradle by setting the jmeterUserProperties in 
jmeterRun.configure but it doesn't work.

It seems my Jmeter plugins are not loaded at all.

How can I translate my command line to Jmeter plugin in Gradle? Even some hints to go to the right direction will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Sébastien.

Comment: Which JMeter plugin are you using? I would recommend you use the one I wrote :) I believe I currently have support for all the options you listed above. See here: https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Advanced-Usage

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that [Gradle plugin to run JMeter tests](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin) you can set user settable parameter:

```
List<String> jmPluginJars
```

You can find other parameters on [GitHub Plugin Wiki page](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Advanced-Usage)